# How to create jceks file in hadoop programmatically using java or python

Tags: java, hadoop, keystore, jceks

I am trying to figure it out on how to create jceks file programmatically instead of below hadoop command.

```
hadoop credential create ssl.server.keystore.password -value 123 \
  -provider localjceks://file/home/lmccay/aws.jceks
```

I was able to find on how to decrypt it but no clue on how to create one

Comment: Both Java and Python can run shell commands such as this line. Also, `hadoop credential create` command is open-source, if you really wanted to find how it worked in the Java code